# Most efficient way of splitting long string into substrings in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, split, substring

I am working on a function in MATLAB which compares two gene sequences and determines their similarity. For this I am partitioning both sequences into smaller substrings by moving through them using for loops, moving by one nucleotide at a time and adding the substrings into cell arrays.

So for example the string ATGCAAAT with a substring length of 4 would not be split as

ATGC , AAAT

but rather as

ATCG , TGCA, GCAA , CAAA , AAAT

I am trying to make the execution of the function faster, and because these two for loops give almost 90% of the execution time, I was wondering if there would be a faster method in MATLAB to do this.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
 SubstrSequence1 = {};                                                
 SubstrSequence2 = {};
 for i = 1:length(Sequence1)-(SubstringLength-1)                
     SubstrSequence1 = [SubstrSequence1, Sequence1(i:i+SubstringLength-1)];
 end

 for i = 1:length(Sequence2)-(SubstringLength-1)                
     SubstrSequence2 = [SubstrSequence2, Sequence2(i:i+SubstringLength-1)]; 
 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
str = 'ATGCAAAT';
n = 4;
strs = str(bsxfun(@plus, 1:n, (0:numel(str)-n).'));
```

The result is a *2D char array*:

```
strs =
ATGC
TGCA
GCAA
CAAA
AAAT
```

so the partial strings are `strs(1,:)`, `strs(2,:)` etc.

If you want the result as a *cell arrray of strings*, add this at the end:

```
strs = cellstr(strs);
```

to produce

```
strs = 
    'ATGC'
    'TGCA'
    'GCAA'
    'CAAA'
    'AAAT'
```

and then the partial strings are `strs{1}`, `strs{2}` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot,this works great. It is about 3 times faster than the for loop I had, and ever so slightly faster than the other suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) to get `SubstrSequence1` -

```
A = 1:numel(Sequence1);
out = cellstr(Sequence1(hankel(A(1:SubstringLength),A(SubstringLength:end)).'))
```

You can follow the same procedure to find `SubstrSequence2`.

Sample run -

```
>> Sequence1 = 'ATGCAAAT';
>> SubstringLength = 4;
>> A = 1:numel(Sequence1);
>> cellstr(Sequence1(hankel(A(1:SubstringLength),A(SubstringLength:end)).'))
ans = 
    'ATGC'
    'TGCA'
    'GCAA'
    'CAAA'
    'AAAT'
```

Comment: I started off with `hankel`,  but couldn't get it to work!

Comment: @LuisMendo I started with bsxfun, but was too late! :)

Comment: I was sure you had started with that :-P

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to generate a matrix of indices that appropriately extract the substrings you desire:

```
>> sequence = 'ATGCAAAT';
>> subSequenceLength = 4;
>> numSubSequence = length(sequence) - subSequenceLength + 1;
>> idx = repmat((1:numSubSequence)', 1, subSequenceLength) + repmat(0:subSequenceLength-1, numSubSequence, 1);
>> result = sequence(idx)

    result =

        ATGC
        TGCA
        GCAA
        CAAA
        AAAT
```